# How can I get a Java TemporalAccessor from a millisecond since Epoch timestamp?

Tags: java, time, epoch

I have a `long` timestamp that is milliseconds since Epoch.

I am calling a third-party API that takes a `TemporalAccessor`.

How do I get one from the other?

Is `Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp)` sufficiently correct, given epoch is UTC?

Comment: What API are you using? What temporal fields does it need?

Comment: "a third-party API" doesn't make it clearer at all. Does it have a *name*? Do you have some links to the documentation, that explains the requirements for the `TemporalAccessor`, such as what temporal fields it need to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be correct, assuming you got your `long` from [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 e.g. [System.currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), and not some [other epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) on `Instant.ofEpochMilli`:

> Obtains an instance of Instant using milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

In other words, it returns milliseconds since UNIX epoch.

You can then readily pass the `Instant` instance to the API that expects the `TemporalAccessor` as `Instant` is an implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question, and have accepted the correct answer to the question as asked.

However, there are related issues implied but not asked in the question.

`TemporalAccessor` is a very generic interface. Many of the Java Time API objects, like `Instant`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` etc., implement this interface. The accepting code will have expectations as to what fields the specific instance of the `TemporalAccessor` supports.

The Third Party API I was using - Stella (https://github.com/mpgirro/stalla) - for generating RSS Feeds simply stated it needed a `TemporalAccessor` when in fact it really needed an `OffsetDateTime`.

In my case, I needed to do

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime()
```

Comment: Instead of `Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime()`, you can simply use `Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`